# Shell script with case statement and loop for not working

Tags: linux, aix

trying to connect in servers list and execute some commands, this script dont execute second step (AIX)

SO=`uname -s`

for server in $(cat maq)
do

```
case $SO in

Linux)
    echo "Connecting in $server"
    ssh  $server 
    echo "my system is $SO" 
    "exit"
    ;;

AIX)
   echo "Connecting in $server"
   ssh  $server
   echo "my system is $SO"
   "exit"
   ;;

esac
```

done

They execute "my server is Linux" for all case choice! Any Help?

Comment: Why do you write a `case` when you're doing the same thing anyway? :-)

Comment: Did you mean`case $server in ...`?

Answer (score 0):

(Edited to make it more clear)

You seem to confuse the local OS with the remote OS. The former won't change during the cycle, only the latter. Here is a complete example.

```
LocalOs="$(uname -s)"
case "$LocalOs" in
Linux)
    echo "Local OS is $LocalOs";
    ;;
AIX)
    echo "Local OS is $LocalOs";
    ;;
*)
    echo "Local OS is $LocalOs";
    ;;
esac

while read server; do
    RemoteOs=$(ssh </dev/null "$server" 'uname -s')
    case "$RemoteOs" in
    Linux)
        echo "OS on $server is $RemoteOs"
        ;;
    AIX)
        echo "OS on $server is $RemoteOs"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "OS on $server is $RemoteOs"
        ;;
    esac
done <"maq"
```

Edit: also you misunderstood how `ssh` works in a script. This doesn't work:

```
ssh remoteuser@remotehost
commands to be executed on remotehost
exit
```

This works:

```
ssh remoteuser@remotehost <<EOF
commands to be executed on remotehost
EOF
```

Simpler case:

```
ssh remoteuser@remotehost 'command(s) to be executed on remotehost'
```

Comment: Hi friend, no, i need test e send command by SO type! Case Linux or in Case AIX